# Where can I change the default setting which browser to use when starting MAMP's starting page (MAMP 3.0.6, MAC)

Tags: browser, configuration, default, mamp, setting

Hej,
when I open the starting page out of MAMP's app it always opens in Chrome. I simply want to change this setting to Firefox but I can't find where to ...

Thank you for your hints!
Mary

Comment: @Alverto Well, chrome is my default browser indeed. And I want it to remain my default browser. I hoped to go the other way round - that I can tell MAMP explicitly which browser to use ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have Chrome as your default browser. If you want Firefox to open up when starting MAMP's app, change the default browser to Firefox.